# Git pull downloads everything even files that haven't changed

Tags: git, github, salesforce, atlassian-sourcetree, git-pull

I am using **Sourcetree** and I used the **git pull** command and instead of **downloading only the updated** files it want's to **download everything**, even files without changes that I didn't even touch.

What I mean is when I use git pull I get every file even if I haven't modified them only because the save date got changed.
I am using git version 2.38.1.windows.1 and SourceTree 3.4.10

Comment: Git does not download (nor upload) individual files. Instead, Git works with *commits* and its internal object model. Normally you would not see the kind of behavior you're seeing; please give more detail.

Comment: Did you execute `git config --global core.autocrlf true` or similar as recommended in https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/git-and-git-hub-basics/work-with-the-git-hub-workflow ? You may not see newline characters as changes because your diff is set to ignore them - but they may well be there

Comment: Can you describe how you see that git "downloads everything" ? if you started from a clone of your repository, running `git pull` to get the updates for your code should indeed download only the new files. Do you run `git pull` from a repo which doesn't have the complete previous history of your repo ?

Comment: Sorry I modified the question so that it is more clear:
What I mean is when I use git pull I get every file even if I haven't modified them only because the save date got changed.
I read on the internet that to ignore metadata I should use :
git config --unset core.filemode
git config --global core.filemode false
but I don't know what they do and the Git documentation talks in gibberish that my Junior Developer brain is too dumb to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who understands my problem and might look for a solution,
**git config --unset core.filemode**
and
**git config --global core.filemode false**
They worked to ignore metadata and not show every file as modified even if it wasn't.

I found this explanation online:

> In Git, the git config core.filemode false command is used to set the
> core.filemode configuration option to false. This configuration option
> controls whether Git considers the execute permission bits of a file
> when determining whether the file has been modified. By setting this
> option to false, Git will ignore the execute permission bits of a file
> and only consider changes to the content of the file when determining
> whether it has been modified. This can be useful if you want to avoid
> downloading files that have only had their execute permission bits
> changed, but not their actual content.
> However, it's important to note that setting the core.filemode
> configuration option to false can also have some drawbacks. For
> example, if you make changes to the execute permission bits of a file
> and then set this option to false, Git will not consider those changes
> as modifications and will not track them. This can lead to confusion
> and make it difficult to maintain the correct execute permission bits
> for your files. It's generally recommended to only use this
> configuration option in specific cases where you need to avoid
> downloading files with only changed execute permission bits.
>
> In Git, the git config core.autocrlf true command is used to set the
> core.autocrlf configuration option to true. This configuration option
> controls how Git handles line endings in text files. By setting this
> option to true, Git will automatically convert line endings in text
> files to the appropriate style for the platform that the files are
> being committed on.
> For example, if you're working on a Windows machine, which uses a
> different line ending style than a Unix-based machine, setting the
> core.autocrlf option to true will automatically convert the line
> endings in text files to the Windows-style line endings when you
> commit the files on a Windows machine, and will convert them back to
> Unix-style line endings when you checkout the files on a Unix-based
> machine. This can help ensure that your text files are consistent and
> portable across different platforms.
> However, it's important to note that setting the core.autocrlf
> configuration option to true can also have some drawbacks. For
> example, if you're working with files that are not text files (such as
> binary files), setting this option to true can cause Git to corrupt
> those files when it attempts to convert the line endings. It's
> generally recommended to only use this configuration option if you're
> working with text files and need to ensure consistency and portability
> across different platforms.